# Renaming a json as *.environment.json and not able to import the same in postman

Tags: environment-variables, logic, postman

I have the below json file.

1) I renamed it as `mytest.environment.json` and I am trying to import the same in postman client app. I am getting an error - format not recognized. (all values are null intentionally)

2) I am not able to connect https://api.getpostman.com/environments to create an environment.

3) If this can not be done, how can I tie an `environment` name to a request inside test script? For e.g, I have a collection, which needs to run against multiple environments . I could not find any API which logs `environment.name`. When I do `console.log(environment)`, it just prints that its an object.

```
{
    "environment": {
        "name": "Test Environment",
        "US_DC": [{
                "enabled": true,
                "key": "oauth_server",
                "value": "",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "enabled": true,
                "key": "oauth_secret",
                "value": "",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "enabled": true,
                "key": "grant_type",
                "value": "",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "enabled": true,
                "key": "api_gateway",
                "value": "",
                "type": "text"
            }
        ],
        "EU_DC": [{
                "enabled": true,
                "key": "oauth_server",
                "value": "",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "enabled": true,
                "key": "oauth_secret",
                "value": "",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "enabled": true,
                "key": "grant_type",
                "value": "",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "enabled": true,
                "key": "api_gateway",
                "value": "",
                "type": "text"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```